# Need help in writing XPATH for Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

Below is the element in DOM.

```
<div style="float:left;width: 40px">
<label class="radio inline">
<input id="formData99991:Select" class="sample" data-ng-model="sampletId" size="" name="formData99991Select" sample-value="true" style="" value="1234" checked="checked" type="radio"/>
A
</label>
</div>
```

I tried with `//input[contains(@id,'formData99991:Select') and contains(text(),'A')]` but it doesn't work. 
There are multiple similar elements on the web page and I need to identify each element with combo of id and text.

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: I pasted it in the question. But, it is not appearing here..Please find below         <div style="float:left;width: 40px">
<label class="radio inline">
<input id="formData99991:Select" class="sample" data-ng-model="sampletId" size="" name="formData99991Select" sample-value="true" style="" value="1234" checked="checked" type="radio"/>
A
</label>
</div>

Comment: why don't you use firepath for firebug so you can inspect the element and they give you directly the correct xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with following x-path,

```
//label[contains(.,'A')]/input[@id="formData99991:Select"]
```